# ImageView not displayed in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, imageview

All I want to do is to put an image stored on the sdcard into an ImageView inside of a fragment.

I used this tutorial for the Navigation Drawer Layout:
https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

And this one for the deeper implementation:
https://www.swipetips.com/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/

This is the fragment1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/workingimageview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
<!--
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/Fragment1"
    android:id="@+id/textview1" />
-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the xml containing the content and the drawer navigation:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- Slideout Menü -->
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This is the fragment onCreateView source code:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle   
    savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);

    /** Load temporary image */
    /** Check if folder exists first */

    if(checkForWorkingDirectory())
    {
        workingImageView = (ImageView) 
                    rootView.findViewById(R.id.workingimageview);
          workingImageView.setImageBitmap(scaleImage.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(returnAbsoluteFilePath(),100,100));
    }


    return rootView;

    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, null);
}
```

checkForWorkingDirectory() basically looks up the directory the image is located in 
and returnAbsoluteFilePath() speaks for itself :)

The ImageView is not displayed at all. However if I comment out the ImageView and
just display the TextView, the text is displayed just fine.

I also tried this because when I load the image I don't know the dimension of the ImageView by then:
http://adanware.blogspot.de/2012/06/android-getting-measuring-fragment.html

Basing on the tutorials I used what is the best and correct way to display an ImageView inside the fragment?

Comment: How are you setting "src" for ImageView?  Can you share that code?

Comment: Editted the code in ;) the values "100","100" are just an example.They should be read somehow in order to fit the whole availabe size of the containing fragment.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

The error was somewhere else.Somewhere I would've never guessed.Since the solution is not related it is not necessary to be posted here.

Comment: Having same problem, would be nice to see if your solution would have fixed mine, even if not related.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing the same issue in my code I found my problem after ACTUALLY LOOKING at my logs where I found the following error.

Bitmap too large to be uploaded into a texture (2340x4160, max=4096x4096).

I solved my problem by extending ImageView class and overloading setImageBitmap and onMeasure methods.

public class ScaledImageView extends ImageView {

```
private Bitmap mBitmap;

public ScaledImageView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public ScaledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
public void setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
    mBitmap = bm;
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int parentWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

    if (mBitmap != null) {
        int w = mBitmap.getWidth();
        int h = mBitmap.getHeight();
        int scaledHeight = (int)(((float)parentWidth / (float)w) * h);
        super.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, parentWidth, scaledHeight, true));
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}